# Editing Devise user in one view and requiring password only for some fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am using Devise with Ruby on Rails and I would like to set up a view for editing user in which I have to provide current password only if I want to have a new password. In other words - if I want to change my name or birthdate, I can simply leave the password fields empty but if I want to change password, I would like to have standard devise behaviour. 

My edit form looks like this:
[image: view]

I tried to allow update without password as written [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) by overriding update_resource method:

```
protected

def update_resource(resource, params)
  resource.update_without_password(params)
end
```

However, without removing `current_password` from `params.require(:user).permit(...)` I receive the following error:

[image: error]

and I can't remove it from permitted params since I want to have it in case of password change.

What would be the way to do it? I am thinking of splitting the view and creating a new form for password editing along with a controller for password edit but I would prefer to have it all in one place.

Comment: Does my answer resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I wrote a comment in which I thanked you and I guess I didn't click 'add comment' -_- Your answer was very helpful and straight to the point :) I've made only a little upgrade replacing the code between "else" and "end" with just "super" :)

Comment: Glad to hear! Feel free to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> unknown attribute 'current_password' for User

The error makes sense as the `current_password` *isn't one the default attribute available in the user that comes with the Devise*. I had the similar issue and I've solved it with the help of `attr_accessor`

In `user.rb` model put `attr_accessor :current_password`. This resolves the error *however you need to tweak the params like below to satisfy both cases*.

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
  if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
    resource.update_without_password(some_params)
  else
    resource.update_with_password(some_params)
  end
end

def some_params
  params.require(:user).permit(--all params here with current_password also included--)
end
```